# Create floating maximum for Table

Tags: analytics, cognos, cognos-11

I'm sadly out of ideas. I'm currently learning in COGNOS analytics and I could use your help.
I have crosstable that looks like this and comes from different system that uses the same source structure. I use company account and am a user, so I cannnot sadly write SQL or any scripts!

```
        MIS0 MIS1 MIS3 MIS6
2016    0,0  0,1  0,3  0,6
2017    0,0  0,1  0,4  0,7
2018    0,0  0,2  0,4  0,7
```

I replicated this in COGNOS but cannot get one thing right (it's much more difficult than than but I think that this is the core)

explanation:

- MIS = months in service
- years = year of product manufactury
- values = (faults / manufactured (that year) and sold products) * 1000

Fault has property MIS = which MIS it happened in, also product has property something like dateOfManufacture

ok so the problem... to have e.g. MIS6 means: Fault that happened within 6 months since purchase. The complication starts that MIS3 fault logically belongs to MIS6 fault too.

So I need to create data-element or filter or some other trick that would enable me to:
select faults relevant for MIS from 0 to X where X will be the number in the header for columns (0,1,3,6...) based of course on year of manufacture .. I'm limited by my user rights so please if you have a suggestion that contains writing a script, thank you, you roll! :) but I won't be able to do it via script.
Excuse the lack of details but named variables or any code is a part of the confidetiality I'm bound by. :(

Thank you for the time and have a nice weekend!

```
Fault
MIS: 2
ProductID: <121212>

Product
ProductID: <121212>
Date of assembly: 25.02.2020
(MIS: gets copied to product fault when fault occours)
```

Table is supposed to view faults that have happened in specific months in service - that means that if fault is as above example says in 2 months in service, it should be calculated into columns MIS3 and MIS6 and not calculated into MIS1 and MIS0 statistics since the fault didn't occour in 1 months but in 2.

**Basically e.g. the first row second column says: find me products that have been manufactured in 2016 - count how many faults they had in first month in service. This number divide by the number of products you found (first sentence) and all this multiply by 1000 (faults/1000)**
As you can now probably see the problem occours when you move to next column on the same row. -> find me products that have been manufactured in 2016. Count how many fault they had in 3 months of service (= 1,2,3 included) and then divide by the number of products made - multiply by 1000.

When I set up crosstab I need to use inteval (MIS0 - MIS1,3,6) with floating maximum, but I don't have the brain to make it..

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying that the crosstab is the *input* to this process?  You can't get to the actual data?  And your output is the number of faults per (months since purchase) and (the year the product was manufactured)?  So basically if you remove the (manufactured and sold products count) from the input you have the output you need?

Comment: last column first row are faults manifested in 6 months in service (for products manufactured in 2016) / products manufactured in 2016 *1000 .    So this includes also faults from MIS3 etc .. The problem is that the formula should be faults from 0 to X where the X is the appropriate MIS

Comment: The filter is now basically MIS<=6 .. but this shows me only one column .. I need MIS <= X

Comment: Please provide sample input and the desired output.

Comment: edited the desired input/output

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but I don't think I see the sample input and output.  Does your database really contain columns with names like MIS0 and MIS1 with character data containing values like "0,1"?  Do your users want output that looks like the code block that begins with the word "Fault"?

Or do I have these swapped?  Is the second code block the input?  (I don't know how Cognos would be able to read that.)  Is the first code block the output?  (A crosstab with character values like "0,1" in the intersection.)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a list first.  If this works, we can convert the list to a crosstab

Let's start by isolating the metric in context to time

This would be your first column

For one month.  Create a data item [Month 1 Faults] like this:

```
if ([Year] = 2016 and [Month] = 1)Then([Faults])Else(0)
```

Next column is for both month 1 and 2.  We add the function IN(1,2) to accomplish this

Create a data item [Month 1 & 2 Faults] like this:

```
if ([Year] = 2016 and [Month] IN(1,2))Then([Faults])Else(0)
```

repeat this logic for all of the other data items